# Autonomous RC plane

Tags: autopilot

I have bought a Kakute F4 V2 Mini from HolyBro for an autonomous RC plane.
The **M1-M6 pins** can be used for the ESCs and servos right?
And which pin has to be used for receiver (works on **iBus**).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Everything is explained in the manual for this board:
http://www.holybro.com/manual/Holybro_KakuteF4_V2_mini_Manual.pdf

"Solder the ESC signal wires to the M1, M2, M3, and M4 pads.
Solder the receiver signal wire to pad R3. If you are using a typical cable, the signal wire will be white or yellow. Pad R3 will automatically configure inversion depending on what serial protocol you are using (SBUS, iBus, Spektrum, etc…). So you will use pad R3 for any receiver."

From Experience HolyBro products are usually nicely documented.

Comment: Ok thank you very much 
But I am using it for an RC plane so I will be connecting Servos to M1 M2 M4 and M3 I will connect the ESC.

I have a small doubt that M1 M2 M3 M4 are labelled in the same way right corresponding to channel 1 channel 2 channel 3 and channel 4?

Comment: Set up the model in the flight control software, and it will tell you. Note you can damage analog servos by sending them 400hz, so make sure that you have the right pins configured before connecting servos